# XSLT - Adding multiple xml element values containing $ sign

Tags: xpath, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

I am trying to write an XSLT code where I have to add all the amount values present in the below snippet of the xml file:

XML:

```
<AmountDetails>
    <Amount>
        <PremiumAmount>$100</PremiumAmount>
        <PremiumAmount>$200</PremiumAmount>
        <PremiumAmount>$300</PremiumAmount>
    </Amount>
    <Amount>
        <PremiumAmount>$300</PremiumAmount>
        <PremiumAmount>$400</PremiumAmount>
        <PremiumAmount>$600</PremiumAmount>
    </Amount>
</AmountDetails>
```

XSLT:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
    
        <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
        <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="AmountDetails"/>
        </xsl:template>
    
        <xsl:template match="AmountDetails">
             <sum>
                 <value>sum(substring(//PremiumAmount),2,4)</value>
             </sum>
        </xsl:template>
        
     
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

But I am getting the below error message:

A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of fn:substring() ("$100", "$200"...)

Answer (score 1):

In XSLT 2.0 you can do simply:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/AmountDetails">
    <sum>
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(Amount/PremiumAmount/number(substring(., 2)))"/>
    </sum>
</xsl:template>
        
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I tried this approach and it worked. Does this approach works only if I am using XSLT version 2 or higher and not if I am using XSLT version 1?

Comment: Yes. In XSLT 1.0, you need to either (a) use a variable to convert the amounts to numbers, then convert the variable from result-tree-fragment to a node-set, and finally sum the numbers or (b) use a recursive named template to add up the amounts one by one.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work as is because it's trying to apply the `substring` function to a set of nodes when it needs to be applied to a string (node text content).

I would like there to be a better way of doing this, but here's what I got (XSLT 1.0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    extension-element-prefixes="exsl">

...

<xsl:template match="AmountDetails">
    <xsl:variable name="x">
        <xsl:for-each select="//PremiumAmount">
            <item><xsl:value-of select="substring(., 2, 4)" /></item>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:value-of select="sum(exsl:node-set($x)/item)" />
</xsl:template>

...

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Basically, we create a variable x that looks like this:

```
<item>100</item>
<item>200</item>
<item>300</item>
...
```

And then we sum the expression `$x/item`, which selects all the item nodes in x.

Comment: I tried this approach too and it worked. I believe this approach will work in both XSLT version 1 and XSLT version 2. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I've updated the answer to work with XSLT 1.0. Michael's answer below for XSLT 2.0 seems to be the clean way to do it if you can use that version.